# How to calculate the powers of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need the powers $A^n$ of the following matrix 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & t & 1-t\\1-t & 0 & t\\ t & 1-t & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with real $t$, but I get messed up in the calculations since, if I'm not mistaken, two eigen values are non-real complex.

Can someone help?

Comment: Diagonalization?

Comment: For this kind of matrices, see [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues). The eigenvectors are actually easier to get than the eigenvalues (as they are always the same); you may work in that basis without explicitly doing the basis transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A=tM+(1-t)M^2$. [Diagonalize $M$ as $M=SJS^{-1}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Jordan%20decomposition%20%7B%7B0,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,1%7D,%7B1,0,0%7D%7D), where $J$ is a diagonal matrix. Then $A^n= S(tJ+(1-t)J^2)^n S^{-1}$.

Comment: Even without using diagonalization the observations that $A=tM+(1-t)M^2$ and $M^3$ simplify the computations with the matrix $M$.